# Properties in asp.net ? Declarations of Properties?

Tags: asp.net

in web application, i am trying to declare property, i found in some of blogs that they declare property like this :

```
 public System.Nullable<DateTime> LoginDateTime { get; set; }
```

what is the meaning of the above property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an [auto-implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make
>   property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required
>   in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create
>   objects. When you declare a property as shown in the following
>   example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that
>   can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

The compiler will transform this code into something like:

```
private System.Nullable<DateTime> xxx;
public System.Nullable<DateTime> LoginDateTime
{ 
    get
    {
        return xxx;
    }
    set
    {
        xxx = value;
    }
}
```

The "generated" code is then called a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx):

> A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read,
>   write, or compute the value of a private field. Properties can be used
>   as if they are public data members, but they are actually special
>   methods called accessors. This enables data to be accessed easily and
>   still helps promote the safety and flexibility of methods.

---

**About System.Nullable<>**

Value type cannot have a null value (compared to reference types). The use of `System.Nullable<>` allows representing the correct range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value.

Another notation to `System.Nullable<DateTime>` is `DateTime?`

[Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's declaring a LoginDateTime property that can either contain a value or be null; it's equivalent to this:

```
 public DateTime? LoginDateTime { get; set; }
```

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What part of it are you confused about?

It happens to be a [C# property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) of type [Nullable(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), which is a structure that allows you to make other structures nullable. As in you can set the property to `null`, Note, you can't set a normal `DateTime` variable to null.

The property is written with some syntactic sugar called [Auto-Implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Having the name *LoginDateTime* it probably stores the Date and Time of when the person logged on.